# Operators and physical quantities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, terminology, observables

Why, in quantum mechanics, do some authors say "physical quantities **are** operators" rather than "physical quantities are **measured by** operators"?

Comment: I would say that physical quantities are represented by operators whose eigenvalues are the possible measured values of those quantities.

Answer (score 2):

In the traditional formulation of Quantum Mechanics, it is stated that observables (which are physical quantities, like energy, position, momentum etc.) are represented by operators with such and such properties. This is the proper wording, "are represented by". Measurements and their link to theory have to do with the vast subject of "Interpretations of Quantum Mechanics". Operators are abstract mathematical constructs, they measure nothing, people and apparata do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the particular authors might be talking about since you haven't included any references.**But**, in the formulation of QM, we use unitary operators that when acted upon states, produce eigenvalues which are the measured physical quantities. For example, when we acted with the momentum operator on a momentum eigenstate, the eigenvalue is the momentum of our quantum system.

$$
\mathcal{\hat{P}}|p\rangle=\mathcal{P}|p\rangle
$$